# Make a calculation on data using fields from Django model

Tags: django, model, calculation

I would like to compute the XIRR using the data from several attributes of a Model

Pretty new to Django, so haven't given it an actual try so far. Though, for the past days actively checking on the web/documentation on how to get started.

Basically I want to compute the XIRR of an investment. So far, I have created a model (Investment) which has 3 attributes: name, date and cash flow. An investment can have of multiple instances (cf an investment can have multiple cash-flows at different dates), and the idea is to compute (and output) the XIRR using this data. How can I tackle this? Aggregations? Annotations? Model Methods? Does anyone has a different function which I can use as an example? Many thanks to give me some guidance so I can get started !!

Comment: Well it depends on what you want to do with that data. Do you want to store it as a new field of the model? Do you just want to show it when the user enters a certain view? You should describe that better in the question. However, I believe the django documentation is good enough to solve your problem without much trouble, but you might need to do some reading before finding what you actually need.

Comment: You can use annotations. You didn't post any code or your models so we can't really help you with the code but look up for annotation.

Comment: Hi Shinra. The objective is to display in the view section. Can you give me a link to where to go in the documentation? Annotation such as Navid suggests? thanks

Comment: Please post your model's code and show us what you've tried until now. Also I have no idea what is "XIRR". Maybe show how you would do the calculation using pure python (assuming you fetched the `Investment` objects from database and then perform the calculation), then we might be able to help how to do this directly in a db query.